# text in image to string using swift. is it possible?

Tags: swift, image-processing

Is it possible to get the text from an image and put the text to a variable in swift?

For example, a Hello World image:

[image: img]

the image above has "Hello World!"

is it possible to make the text from that picture and set it to a variable like:

```
var textFromImage = ??
```

I am new to this. sorry if dumb question

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, so many resources out there check this tutorial [textRecognition iOS](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6565-ml-kit-tutorial-for-ios-recognizing-text-in-images)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Use ML Kit (Firebase) or Vision ORC of Google: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr

Checkout example for iOS (Swift/Objective-C): https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/samples